# resharper inline object initialisation

Tags: c#, resharper

I work with resharper and when I clean my code I get this layout:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.Products).Returns(new List<Product>{new Product{Name = "Football", Price =    25}, new Product{Name = "Surf board", Price = 179}, new Product{Name = "Running Shoes", Price = 95}}.AsQueryable());
```

I'd rather have:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.Products).Returns(new List<Product>{
    new Product{Name = "Football", Price = 25}, 
    new Product{Name = "Surf board", Price = 179}, 
    new Product{Name = "Running Shoes", Price = 95}
}.AsQueryable());
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want by using the Resharper Options (Main Menu -> Resharper -> Options).

There are two places you need to look:

[image: Braces Layout > Array and Object InitializerLayout]

And here:

[image: Line Breaks and Wrapping > Object and Collection Initializers]

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Go to Resharper > Tools > Code Editing > C# > Line Breaks and Wrapping. Then set 'wrap object and collection initialiser' to 'chop always'.

It will show you an example of what your option will look like in a window at the bottom. I am using Resharper 6 but I assume it will be a similar process if you are on an earlier version.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the ReSharper menu in Visual Studio and choose 'Options'. Then go to Languages -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Line Breaks and Wrapping. Then on the right side you can set you preferable options (Wrap object and collection initializer). Also under 'Other' you can set to place LinQ queries on different lines.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible to get at least very close to this by [customizing the formatting style](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html#Code_Style_Configuration_and_Sharing) for C#. There's a chance that the options available are not powerful enough to get to this *exact* result, but you will have to try them and see.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
ReSharper -> Options -> Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style
```

Sometimes it gets in conflict with VS, so here maybe too.

```
Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting
```